# Large JSON data takes too much time to load

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular-datatables for tabular pagination of JSON data. My JSON data is of 1000 records and it takes time to load. I want to load only 100 records at the very first time and when I click on 'Next' button, the next 100 records should gets loaded. I am new in Angular please help me and guide.

Comment: There are many free tutorials in internet, please go through it and try to implement the requirement. if you stuck, please post the code, so that we can help  https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

Comment: @Deepak I have gone through all of them and this problem is not of that tutorials level.

Comment: I understand Arun, we are trying to help you. Please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Deepak I will not go through your provided link.

Comment: If you are using Spring on the server side, you can view my blog entry on using Angular-datatables with server side pagination: https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2016/05/05/angular-datatables-with-server-side-pagination-using-spring-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay that might reduce the time taken to load your files but on the contrary it makes you send **100** requests to the server which is not good.
When dealing with huge data you cannot expect much speed. But, You can optimize the ng-repeat performance by using

1. [Track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)
2. [BindOnce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)
3. [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll)

These things will improve the performance to an extent.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is appreciable. So eventually you want to say that I cannot achieve the first 100 records loading at very first time and on click next button loads next 100 records from server as it sends 10 more request to load 1000 records.

Comment: Exactly. It will increase the load on the server as it has to handle more requests. So a better option would be using some optimizing techniques. BindOnce is really helpful to increase the performance you should try that.

Comment: erm, what if the user only normally looks at the first 100 rows, you just slowly loaded all of the rest of the data for nothing. @ArunArya I think its incorrect to suggest that server-side paging arbitrarily puts excessive load on the server.